# Creating a turn by turn navigation app for Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to create a navigation map where I put several stops along a route and have turn by turn navigation supplied to the driver (icons, not just pins).

The Google Maps API terms of service say it's not allowed:

> No navigation. You will not use the Service or Content for or in
>   connection with (a) real-time navigation or route guidance; or (b)
>   automatic or autonomous vehicle control.

Apps like Uber break this rule. I read somewhere that these companies have contracts with Google. How would I get one?

Comment: Your quote is from old version of Google Maps APIs Terms of Service. Now (since July 16, 2018) [here](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/) is new version.

Comment: If you are interested in Navigation SDK for Android you should contact Google sales: https://enterprise.google.com/maps/contact-form/index.html